# rails sidekiq background process

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, background-process, sidekiq

i'm having an issue configuring the sidekiq server, the process seems to be running in the foreground as soon as i refresh my page. /consumers/fetch i need to put it in the background permanently.

## consumers_controller.rb

```
require 'kafka'

class ConsumersController < ApplicationController

  def fetch

    @consumer = Kafka::Consumer.new( { :host => ENV["host"],
        :port => ENV["port"],
        :topic => ENV["topic"]})

    @consumer.loop do |message|
      logger.info "-------------#{message.inspect}--------------"
      logger.info "-------------#{message.first.payload.inspect}--------------"
      unless message.blank?
        ConsumerWorker.perform_async(message.first.payload)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

## consumer_worker.rb

```
class ConsumerWorker

  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(message)
    payload = message.first["payload"]
    hash = JSON.parse(payload)
    return @message = Message.new(hash) if hash["concern"] == 'order_create' or hash["concern"] == 'first_payment'
  end

end
```

## message.rb

```
class Message

  attr_reader :bundle_id, :order_id, :order_number, :event

  def initialize(message)
    @payload = message["payload"]
    @bundle_id = @payload["bundle_id"]
    @order_id  = @payload["order_id"]
    @order_number = @payload["order_number"]
    @event = message["concern"]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move this block

```
@consumer.loop do |message|
end
```

inside your worker somehow, as I think the consumption is done after block execution.

Comment: Hassan, @consumer.loop is a continuous loop, the implementation is while(true){ process mesesage }. i don't know how does the process return from this

Comment: actually, now that I've taken a closer look at it, sidekiq is not supposed to return you anything.
this line: 
return @message = Message.new(hash) if hash["concern"] == 'order_create' or hash["concern"] == 'first_payment'

does not return control back to the caller.